# In MATLAB, how do I use legend with colormap in a scatter plot

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, how do I use legend with colormap in a scatter plot?

For example:

```
colormap winter
xData = [1 2 3 4 5];
yData = [7 4 2 8 1];
col = [1 1 2 2 1];
h1 = scatter(xData, yData, 50, col,'s');
legend('one','two')
```

Obviously this legend is wrong as it only shows 'one'. I know that I could split up the data by `col` and plot two scatter plots but there must be a simple way of making a legend when using a colormap?

Comment: Try `gscatter` instead of `scatter`

Comment: Thanks @Daniel but I didn't think gscatter worked for this type of data? i.e. there must be one value of G for each row of X.

Comment: `legend` adds a label for each data set. In your code, there is only one set of data, even though you "splitted" the data by "color".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would plot the data using `gscatter`:

```
gscatter(xData,yData,col)
legend('one','two')
```

Obviously the output is optically not identical to `scatter`, but `gscatter` seems to be the right choice if you want to group your points by `col`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, which preserves the scatter()-style i would suggest to to use scatter in a loop, one call for each of your groups. Therefore we create the colormap, which would be used and assign the colors manually:

```
xData = [1 2 3 4 5];
yData = [7 4 2 8 1];
col = [1 1 2 2 1];
groups = unique(col);
nGroups = length(groups);
cmap = colormap(winter(nGroups));
figure
hold on
for iGroup = 1:nGroups
    group = groups(iGroup);
    idx = col==group;
    scatter(xData(idx), yData(idx), 50, cmap(iGroup,:),'s');
end
legend('one','two')
```

Comment: This solution disrupts the randomized order of the scattered points and will place the last color on top of the rest of the colors.